# Constructing an object with JS map results in some undefined keys. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, higher-order-functions

Am I crazy?

I have two functions:

```js
export const timeblocks = (data) => {
  const res = data.map((d) => timeblock(d));
  console.log("tbs res[0].start", res[0].start);
  console.log("tbs res", res);
  return res;
}

export const timeblock = (data) => {
  const res = {
    id: data.id,
    start: moment(data.start),
    end: moment(data.end),
    duration: moment.duration(data.duration),
    timezone: data.timezone,
  };
  // return Object.freeze(res);
  console.log("tb res.start", res.start);
  console.log("tb res", res);
  return res;
}
```

I'm passing data through like this: `timeblocks(sampleData)`:

```
sampleData = [
  {
    "id": 1010,
    "start": "2019-11-21T05:00:00Z",
    "end": "2019-11-21T05:30:00Z",
    "duration": "00:30:00",
    "timezone": "UTC"
  },
  {
    "id": 1052,
    "start": "2019-11-21T05:00:00Z",
    "end": "2019-11-21T06:00:00Z",
    "duration": "01:00:00",
    "timezone": "UTC"
  }
]
```

The `start` and `end` keys throw TypeError undefined in my React app.

**However,** I also get this:

[image: Console log for data mapping in js]

Object.freeze **does** work, but why are the values getting converted to undefined?

I can't tell if this is a moment.js thing or a JS thing.

Comment: Can you include some example data?

Comment: you need to paste more code and show how you are calling the two functions you pasted. I think there is some .toValue you'd need to call on the moment.js object also.

Comment: Added sample data! Thanks!

Comment: [I can't reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/rerolabifo/1/edit?js,console). Seems like something else is removing the `start` value after this code runs.

Comment: You might want to JSON.stringify your console logs first. You can test whether it's moment.js by removing the calls to moment. If you see your original data in the start and end members, then it's something about the moment calls.

Comment: I ran the code and it works.

Comment: Yeah I realized why this isn't working in my app and added an answer below. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Something downstream is changing my start and end values. Because the resulting object is mutable, those two values are getting set to undefined. I figured this out be logging just before passing the resulting value into a redux action. Thanks @VLAZ for the advice